# metatag_panels does not work on panel pages

Tags: 7, panels, meta-tags

I want to add the

```
<meta name="keywords"/>
```

tag to my pages.

For this, I have installed the metatag module.

It works fine for all pages except the panel pages. So I activate the metatag_panels module, but it does not help. I can’t find any configuration or special field to activate meta tag on panel pages.

Is there any special configuration or something? Does somebody has any idea how I can get it work?